# Specific terms of Combinations with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I want to solve this problem that I found but until now I have failed. Consider the combinations with repetition that we can make putting N balls in M boxes. So We know that the number of combinations is given by:

C(N,M) = (N+M-1)!/( (M-1)!*N! )

But I am interested  in the number of combinations that fulfill specific conditions. For instance, consider M=3, N=3. Then the possible combinations are:

[3,0,0],[2,1,0],[2,0,1],[0,3,0],[0,0,3],[1,1,1],[0,2,1],[1,2,0],[1,0,2],[0,1,2]

This are 10 terms, since C(3,3)=10. But what is the analytical formula to obtain the combinations of the elements for 0 balls in 1 box , 2 boxes etc? So it's like 1 hole and 2 holes

In our example we have 6 terms that have 1 hole ( 1 box without balls), and 3 terms that have 2 holes (2 boxes without balls). Finally only 1 term with a ball in every box (0 holes). 6+3+1=10

This example is easy but I am looking for a general analytical expresion to obtain that. Do you have some idea?? Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you trying to determine the number of solutions which contain at least one empty box?  In that case, you want to subtract the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{M} = N$$ in the positive integers from the number of solutions of the same equation in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Well I want all the possible combinations that has 1, 2, ..M-1 etc empty boxes. I don't see how your suggestion can solve the problem. Can you make an example?

Comment: In your example, the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$ has $\binom{3 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{5}{2} = 10$ solutions in the nonnegative integers, of which only one is a solution in the positive integers, which is why you have nine solutions in which at least one box is left empty.  If you want to know how many solutions leave exactly $k$ boxes empty, choose which $k$ boxes will be left empty and multiply by the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{M - k} = N$$ in the positive integers.    If you can clarify which question you are asking, I can elaborate later.